# JQuery Issue: Showing hidden object

Tags: jquery

I do have a problem with making my code right. I guess my knowledge is not enough to sort it out so I am asking maybe one of you could kindly fix my code.

So what I am trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/yHHFJ/

```
$('[class^=is]').hide();
$("#select_2").change(function(){          
var value = $("#select_2 option:selected").val();
var theDiv = $(".is" + value);

theDiv.slideDown();
theDiv.siblings('[class^=is]').slideUp();
});

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
function changesizedropdown(size){
var option = size;
var select = document.getElementById("select_2");
var opt, o = 0;
while (opt = select[o++]){
if (opt.value == option){ select.selectedIndex = o - 1; }
}
}

$j(document).ready(function () {

var swatch ='';
$j('#sizebox:eq(0) option').each(function() {swatch = swatch + "<li> <a    href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='changesizedropdown(&amp;quot;"+ $j(this).val() +"&amp;quot;);'>" + $j(this).text() + "</a></li>"});
var sizeswatchhtml = "<div class='size'><div style='float: left; margin: 6px 5px 0px 0px;'>SELECT SIZE : </div><div style='float: left; margin: 0pt 7px 0px 13px;'><ul>"+ swatch + " </ul></div></div>";
document.getElementById('sizeswatch').innerHTML = sizeswatchhtml;

});
```

I have got an select and option dropdown with S M L sizes which I managed to display as separate DIVs. Also I have got hidden DIVs (Small, Medium, Large) which should be displayed when I click on S (show Small), M (show Medium) or L(show Large) but they don't appear and I am struggling  with making it right.

Can you please help me guys?

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I can't understand the logic of your script. I feel it is full of overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some minor changes to your script and seems like its working fine now.

```
<script>

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j('[class^=is]').hide();


$j("#select_2").change(function(){          
process();
});
function process()
{
var value = $j("#select_2 option:selected").val();
var theDiv = $j(".is" + value);
theDiv.slideDown();
theDiv.siblings('[class^=is]').slideUp();
}
function changesizedropdown(size){
var option = size;
var select = document.getElementById("select_2");
var opt, o = 0;
while (opt = select[o++]){
if (opt.value == option){select.selectedIndex = o - 1; process();}
}
}

$j(document).ready(function () {

var swatch ='';
$j('#sizebox:eq(0) option').each(function() {
swatch = swatch + "<li> <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='changesizedropdown(\""+       $j(this).val() +"\");'>" + $j(this).text() + "</a></li>"});
var sizeswatchhtml = "<div class='size'><div style='float: left; margin: 6px 5px 0px    0px;'>SELECT SIZE : </div><div style='float: left; margin: 0pt 7px 0px 13px;'><ul>"+ swatch + " </ul></div></div>";
document.getElementById('sizeswatch').innerHTML = sizeswatchhtml;

});
```

First change is that I have used \" in place of &quot; as it was giving error.

Second change is that even after you were changing the select index of the dropdown list, its change event was not being fired so I have called it explicitly from the function changesizedropdown itself.

Third change is that I have wrote the noconflict statement above all and have used $j inplace of $ everywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you gaurav. I have placed your code in jsfiddle and in my html but it seems not working. When I click on the S, M or L boxes nothing happens like before. Can you please try amend jsfiddle code to see what is wrong?

Comment: Apologies gaurav. Your code is working well. It was my mistake. Thanks a lot.